# How to select a odd numbered element in html?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a website which displays some posts. each post has header class and content class. I want to change the colour of odd no headings into red and even numbered headings to black.

```
            <div class="category_header">
                <h2><a href="#">Heading</a></h2>
            </div> 
            <div class="single-post">           
                <p></p>
            </div>
```

given above is the format of my html code. so by following the [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) i tried something like this

```
.category_header:nth-child(odd) {
background: red;
}
```

now all the headings color changed to red. Some help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to change the colour of odd numbered headings into red and even numbered headings to black.

```
.category_header:nth-of-type(4n+1) h2 a {
  color: red;
}
```

Alternaively, if there are no intervening elements:

```
.category_header:nth-child(4n+1) h2 a {
  color: red;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.category_header:nth-of-type(4n+1) h2 a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="category_header">
  <h2><a href="#">Heading 1</a></h2>

</div>
<div class="single-post">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
</div>
<div class="category_header">
  <h2><a href="#">Heading 2</a></h2>

</div>
<div class="single-post">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>

<div class="category_header">
  <h2><a href="#">Heading 3</a></h2>

</div>
<div class="single-post">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>

<div class="category_header">
  <h2><a href="#">Heading 4</a></h2>

</div>
<div class="single-post">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>

<div class="category_header">
  <h2><a href="#">Heading 5</a></h2>

</div>
<div class="single-post">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for the same reason that I left as comment to Aaron's answer.

Comment: Took me a while to figure out the right xn+y...then I had to build the demo. I already knew the others were wrong.  A simple demo showed that. :)

Comment: I'd recommend sticking with `:nth-child()` instead of changing it to `:nth-of-type()` as that can be misleading.

Comment: Indeed...I was considering. Both would work in this instance though...right?

Comment: @Paulie_D: Yes, because all of the elements are divs.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `:nth-of-type(XX)`

```css
.category_header:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="category_header">
  <h2><a href="#">Heading</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="single-post">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, I don't think this will solve OP's needs because they seem to be trying to select every odd no headings. The above selector would select every odd numbered `div` which also has `class='category_header'`. So if you add another header div after the single post that will also be styled. I do acknowledge that the title is a bit misleading though. (I am not the one to downvote).

Comment: @ harry and @Aaron sorry for my misleading title.

Comment: Ahh, you are right... he needs the non existent `:nth-of-class()`